# Python Optimization on Looping Arrays

Tags: python, performance, loops, memory

This is perhaps too generic, but I don't know how to ask it without TMI.

I have a python program that is creating a 6 x 12 numpy matrix with a unique set of 12 strings in the x and y direction. From what I can tell from running my program, it seems takes about 2000 iterations +/- to produce a solution. If it fails to create a unique solution or the solution provided doesn't meet some qualifications after the initial success, then it starts over.

At this point, I was just looping through the program until I had success. I tried using garbage collection, but it still just chewed through memory (I have 26 GB free) and crashed. I then moved to having `subprocess.call()` and just rerunning the whole program while killing off the old PID.

This has stabilized the memory consumption, but Windows is saying the Python.exe process is 500 MB and I am getting about 340 attempts per minute. I can't tell if this is good or bad. I am 15,000 attempts into my first try. I imagined it would take a ton of attempts, but not sure as to relative speed.

Does this seem slow? Have I messed up the efficiency of the matrices and using too much memory? I don't have any frame of reference on what an optimized calculation time per minute would be. I have a lot more info if anyone is interested.

Here is the main loop where the program spends the most time:

```
def uniquecheck(inning, position, checkplayer, checkarr)
    global xcheck
    uniquelist = []

    if xcheck < 2000:
        y=0
        for row in checkplayer:
            if y <= (inning-2):
                uniquelist.append(checkplayer[y,position])
                y = y + 1
                xcheck = xcheck + 1
        
        columns = checkplayer.shape[1]
        z=0
        for z in range(columns):
            if z != 0:
                if z <= (position-1):
                    uniquelist.append(checkplayer[(inning-1), z])
                    z = z + 1
                xcheck = xcheck + 1
```

Comment: In general, try to avoid explicit looping when using numpy or pandas. They have built-in operations that process the array as a whole, and they're optimized heavily.

Comment: It's impossible to provide a more specific answer since you haven't posted the code.\

Comment: So you have a 6x12 matrix of strings? But what is is you are trying to calculate? You just say it takes 2000 iterations to produce a result. What would a result look like? What is the input and what have you tried so far?

Comment: The result is the 6 x 12 matrix would be similar to Sudoku except with names. Unique in the x  and y direction. The input is just a list of 12 names with some qualifications as to where it can be placed.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry the code is a few thousand lines and it felt like TMI. The main loop is definitely explicit. Should I not be using Numpy?

Comment: I ran tracemalloc at the failures and got (200206, 204922) as the highest number. Any clue how this correlates to the 500 MB Memory Commit showing in Windows? Those numbers seem to be pretty far apart.

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking this timing looks very slow?
https://discourse.quantecon.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-vectorize-recursive-formulations-using-numpy/258/2

Answer (score 0):

I am getting around the problem by testing and failing the solution faster. Instead of filling the full array and then checking it after it's created. I put in some intermediate checks and fail ones that have no chance of passing early and save all the iterations.

Not sure how to speed it up anymore, but at least it isn't 12 hours slow now. I am sure I could continue to optimize the code, but it doesn't seem like it is worth it now that it is working.